# riddle - replace 4 strokes of code in equivalent 2

Tags: assembly, pdp-11

```
tst r0
blt label
cmp r0, #11
bgt label
```

As I understand this peace of code is a brench if r0 < 0 or r0 > 11.

How can I optimize it to only 2 strokes of code.

Comment: Is this really PDP-11?  It looks like valid ARM syntax.  Oh, except for `tst` with one operand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unsigned comparison:

```
cmp r0, #11
bhi label
```

Values below 0 are represented using two's complement.  So, -1 represented as a 16-bit unsigned value is 1111111111111111, which is higher than 11 (which is 0000000000001011).